# Определение даты

Tags: mysql

Ни в какую не хочет определятся дата 00-00-0000.
Только 0000-00-00 и все.

Comment: @LLIAKAJI, так это естественный формат, в котором храниться дата в базе.

Comment: а как сделать что бы хранился день, месяц, год
в php $date = date("d-m-Y"); а там ничего 0000-00-00

Comment: @LLIAKAJI, пардон, а зачем вообще мучать себя вопросом, в каком формате хранится? Хорошим тоном считается хранить дату в **TIMESTAMP**, а обрабатываете как вам надо уже при выводе данных.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function TIMESTAMP() in C:\web\xampp\htdocs\www\user\post.php on line 28
вот как оно тогда реагирует

Comment: @Deonis, это где это считается хорошим тоном хранить дату в TIMESTAMP.

А если надо что бы дата была раньше чем 1970 год?

Comment: Что это за функция такая?)

time() - время в timestamp, date() - преобразование времени в нормальный вид.

Comment: @LLIAKAJI, попробуйсте посмотреть тут:


http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/DATETIME.html

Comment: @LLIAKAJI, не понимаю, что вы пытаетесь сделать. Покажу, как можно вытаскивать в нужном вам формате:

    $query = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`date_field`, "%d.%m.%Y") as mydate FROM `table_name`";

Comment: мне нужен ни SELECT, а записать в БД

Comment: @LLIAKAJI, записать в таком формате получится только в случае, если вы записывать будете в поле с типом, ну скажем, VARCHAR, а это уже не есть гуд. Забудьте вы про то, как хранится в БД. Зачем оно вам надо - не пойму. В итоге, вы же хотите чтоб нормально дата отображалась у пользователя.

Comment: и в базе и в пользователя, но надо день, месяц, год

Answer (score 1):

Кажется, как-то так.

Для вставки в БД:

Если поле типа Datetime:

```
$dates = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('2010-10-12 15:09:00') );
$query = "INSERT INTO timeTable(time) VALUES ('$dates')";
```

Если поле типа Date:

```
$dates = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2010-10-12 15:09:00') );
$query = "INSERT INTO timeTable(time) VALUES ('$dates')";
```

Для вывода в PHP:

```
echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($row['time']) );
```

Подробнее про: [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strtotime.php)

Comment: а что вместо 2010-10-12 15:09:00 писать?